# Is there a way to add an option on the attachments files button in Outlook web add-in?

Tags: javascript, xml, outlook-web-addins

I want to place another option there:
[image: The emplacement I want to put the options]

Is there an another extension point that I missed?

I've been looking for an answer, but I could only put it beside the attachments button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently the feature: add an option on the attachments files button, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [Tech Community Page](http://aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions). Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered when we go through our planning process.